# Robotframework RIDE tool showing error "Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!"

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Below modules are installed on Window 10 PC

```
C:\Users\Pandit>pip list

Package             Version
------------------- -----------
numpy               1.22.3

Pillow              9.0.1
pip                 19.2.3

Pygments            2.11.2

Pypubsub            4.0.3

pywin32             303

robotframework      4.1.3

robotframework-ride 1.7.4.2

setuptools          41.2.0

six                 1.16.0

wxPython            4.0.7.post2
```

While launching ride.py below error is observed :

```
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 70.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 71.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 13.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\application.py", line 58, in OnInit
    self.frame = RideFrame(self, self._controller)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\mainframe.py", line 175, in __init__
    self._init_ui()
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\mainframe.py", line 279, in _init_ui
    self.tree = Tree(self, self.actions,
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\tree.py", line 86, in __init__
    self._images = TreeImageList()
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 42, in __init__
    TestCaseController: _TreeImage(self, 'robot.png'),
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.normal = self._get_image(image_list, normal)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 91, in _get_image
    img = wx.Image(path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1579) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
**Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
OnInit returned false, exiting...
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(478) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed**
```

Looks like RIDE tool is not supporting robotframework in python 3.8.0
Please help here if any solution available.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned on the RIDE project [README](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE#readme):

**The pre-release and current development, supports Python 3.8 (since February 2020).**

So you can try to install the Beta1:

```
Install current Beta version (2.0b1) with:

pip install psutil
pip install -U --pre robotframework-ride
```